# How to respond to the btrfsck information "well this shouldn't happen, extent record overlaps but is metadata?"

Tags: fsck, btrfs

When I run `btrfs check --repair` to try to fix the following error, I got the following output:

```
$ sudo btrfs check --repair /dev/sda1
enabling repair mode
WARNING:

    Do not use --repair unless you are advised to do so by a developer
    or an experienced user, and then only after having accepted that no
    fsck can successfully repair all types of filesystem corruption. Eg.
    some software or hardware bugs can fatally damage a volume.
    The operation will start in 10 seconds.
    Use Ctrl-C to stop it.
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Starting repair.
Opening filesystem to check...
parent transid verify failed on 111692120064 wanted 360498 found 364003
parent transid verify failed on 111692120064 wanted 360498 found 364003
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 29671424 wanted 360534 found 364003
parent transid verify failed on 29671424 wanted 360534 found 364003
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 34750464 wanted 363754 found 364003
parent transid verify failed on 34750464 wanted 363754 found 364003
Ignoring transid failure
Checking filesystem on /dev/sda1
UUID: e75d569a-400c-4076-8b9f-903a7a1f4f03
[1/7] checking root items
parent transid verify failed on 111692120064 wanted 360498 found 364003
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 29671424 wanted 360534 found 364003
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 34750464 wanted 363754 found 364003
Ignoring transid failure
Fixed 0 roots.
[2/7] checking extents
parent transid verify failed on 29671424 wanted 360534 found 364003
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 34750464 wanted 363754 found 364003
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 111692120064 wanted 360498 found 364003
Ignoring transid failure
extent back ref already exists for 21790720 parent 0 root 10
extent back ref already exists for 21839872 parent 0 root 10
extent back ref already exists for 21856256 parent 0 root 10
extent back ref already exists for 22003712 parent 0 root 10
extent back ref already exists for 22036480 parent 0 root 10
extent back ref already exists for 23396352 parent 0 root 10
extent back ref already exists for 23412736 parent 0 root 10
parent transid verify failed on 37912576 wanted 351287 found 364003
parent transid verify failed on 37912576 wanted 351287 found 364003
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 38420480 wanted 351287 found 364003
parent transid verify failed on 38420480 wanted 351287 found 364003
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 38486016 wanted 351287 found 364003
parent transid verify failed on 38486016 wanted 351287 found 364003
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 46858240 wanted 351287 found 364003
parent transid verify failed on 46858240 wanted 351287 found 364003
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 62865408 wanted 363983 found 364003
parent transid verify failed on 62865408 wanted 363983 found 364003
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 67059712 wanted 363983 found 364003
parent transid verify failed on 67059712 wanted 363983 found 364003
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 71417856 wanted 360532 found 364003
parent transid verify failed on 71417856 wanted 360532 found 364003
Ignoring transid failure
Chunk[256, 228, 182558130176]: length(1073741824), offset(182558130176), type(1) is not found in block group
Chunk[256, 228, 192221806592]: length(1073741824), offset(192221806592), type(1) is not found in block group
Chunk[256, 228, 279194894336]: length(1073741824), offset(279194894336), type(1) is not found in block group
Chunk[256, 228, 299595988992]: length(1073741824), offset(299595988992), type(1) is not found in block group
well this shouldn't happen, extent record overlaps but is metadata? [21790720, 16384]

Aborted
```

the `Aborted` is triggered after 1 minute after the prompt, so I assume that `btrfs check` was asking me to make a hard decision. The problem is: what kind of decision do I have and how do I inform the program to conduct the fix?

I'm using ubuntu 22.04, the btrfs is on the second HDD slot without being mounted.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: btrfs is one of the few filesystems which actually can detect when they become damaged and are able to warn the operator, so the operator is able to use a backup. ext4 for example just destroys bugged files/data by filling them up with zeros and after ext4 has don that, it reports that the filesystem is okay again. Maybe the filesystem is okay, but not your data, lol. PS when using btrfs raid1 or btrfs dup, the btrfs filesystem would be able to self-repair at the cost of double space usage.

Answer (score 0):

`btrfs check` isn't asking you to make a decision, but telling you it cannot repair the damage it found.
Your best course of action is to make sure you have good and current backups, and then reformat the partition.